# arrange side bar, navigation bar and footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
/*footer*/
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;

  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

/*navbar*/
.navbar{
 background-color:black;
 
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.navbar-brand{
 font-size: 20px;
 
}
.logo1{
 height: 50px;
 width: 75px;
 opacity: 0.1px;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 position: absolute;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
color: #000;  /*Sets the text hover color on navbar*/
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active >   
 a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
color: white; /*BACKGROUND color for active*/
background-color: #030033;
}

  .navbar-default {
    background-color: #0f006f;
    border-color: #030033;
}

  .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
   .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #262626;
   text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #66CCFF;  /*change color of links in drop down here*/
   }

 .nav > li > a:hover,
 .nav > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: silver; /*Change rollover cell color here*/
  }


  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
   color: whites; /*Change active text color here*/
    }
body > .container {
  padding: 60px 15px 0;
}
.container .text-muted {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
/* side bar*/
/* Toggle Styles */

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
 z-index: 1;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}
.btn>.btn-default{

}


@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />
 <link href="bootstrap.min1.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
  <!--top bar-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   <img class="logo1" src="images/capture.png" alt=" logo">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Web Portax</a>
  </div>
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Account Setting</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Message</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services<span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Edit Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Manage prefrences</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li> 
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>

<div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        Start Bootstrap
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                      
                        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="jquery1.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="bootstrap.min1.js"></script>

    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    </script>



<!-- body-->

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Content</h1>
      </div>
     
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
        <p class="text-muted"> All rights reserved.  </p>
  </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hey guys can anyone help me as my current page looks like this[enter image description here]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNmvT.jpg)

When i click toogle to expand my side bar it looks like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRYSy.jpg)

How can i fix the white spaces that is in between the header and the sidebar? How can i shift the little grey thing to toggle the sidebar to left corner? and lastly how can i shift "Web Portax" from the top nav bar slightly to the right so when i minimize it the logo and the text do not crumple together?

I am new to html thing so sorry for the amateur question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use  the `margin` property in CSS to adjust the space around your elements.

Example:
    `margin-top: 100px;
 margin-bottom: 100px;
 margin-right: 150px;
 margin-left: 80px;`

and the `padding` element to adjust the space in between the content and the border of the element.

Example:

`padding-top: 50px;
 padding-right: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
 padding-left: 80px;`

You can also use the `height` and `width` properties to adjust the size of the element.

Example `height: 100px;`

Comment: Alright i have managed to set the
margin-top: -20px;
 margin-left: -20px;.
However, when i toogle the sidebar it still cover the footer and the content part is there any way that i can fix it?

Comment: did that fix the issue?

Comment: did you adjust the margin of the footer and the content?

Comment: Yes now there isn't any white spaces between the top bar and side bar but i am still confused on the footer, as when i toogled out the sidebar it covered my footer.

Comment: I'm assuming you haven't adjusted the margin separately for the footer div so in your css, adjust `margin-top` attribute until the sidebar no longer covers it. Example: `.footer{ margin-top: 100px;}`

Comment: Alright it seems the side bar has no white spaces. Sorry am i able to make the side bar position absolute when toogled, such that when i zoom out of the page my side bar height and width remain proportional

Comment: are you using `position: absolute;`

Comment: `#sidebar-wrapper` has a fixed position in your code above which may be the problem. But right now your code above gives a weird output so could you maybe post your whole project in like a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so that I can test it

Comment: can i send you by email instead?

Comment: preferably not. if you can get the code above working so that the output looks like whatever you're seeing or if you can post it somewhere else then I can help but otherwise its very difficult to see what the problem is